# How do I ask R to run a specific function from a user defined package to run everytime I load that package?

Tags: r, package, hide

I've created a package `mypack` with only one r script in the R directory of the project, *hello.R* which basically prints our Hello World when loaded and run.  Now i need to add some lines of code to a script (ex-  *hide.R*) so that the contents of the function *hello.R* is not easily visible to a not so experience user. I need this *hide.R* to run first each time the package `mypack` is loaded. Can somebody give me a full working example for this?

> Note: outside a package, if I have a function foo, then the following
>   makes it a little difficult for a normal user to get the function
>   definition easily

```
srcfile <- srcfilecopy("", "Don't cheat")
srcref <- srcref(srcfile, c(1,1,1,12))
attr(foo, "srcref") <- srcref
```

Ultimately, once a user loads my package, he/she should not be easily able to get the contents of my function inside the  package by typing out the function name. This is for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function called `.onLoad` inside your package. See docs here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-hooks.html

Comment: I did that. In fact, I included   `.onLoad <- function(libname = find.package("mypack"), pkgname = "mypack") {
  srcfile <- srcfilecopy("", "Don't cheat")
  srcref <- srcref(srcfile, c(1,1,1,12))
  attr(hello, "srcref") <- srcref
}` in zzz.R and placed it in the R directory of the package along with hello.R. But still, once I load the package using `library(mypack)`, and type `hello`, it prints out the function body! I don't want that to happen. Instead, I want R to print out "Don't Cheat"

Comment: Try adding this to the end of your `.onLoad` function:  `assign("hello", hello, envir = parent.env(environment()))`

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Could you please explain what this means though?